# Roll apply to return moving average

Tags: r

I have a Data vector below and I'd like to calculate a 2 period moving average like this given that there are NAs in the data. So the results I am looking for are:

```
Data    2 period moving average
    NA
    1   1
    2   1.5
    3   2.5
    4   3.5
    5   4.5
    6   5.5
    7   6.5
    8   7.5
    9   8.5
    10  9.5
    NA   10
```

in r I as looking to use roll apply but I am not getting the right results:

```
z <- c(NA,seq(1,10,1),NA)
z
rollapply(z, 2, mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = list(NA, NULL, NA))
[1]  1.0  1.5  2.5  3.5  4.5  5.5  6.5  7.5  8.5  9.5 10.0   NA
```

There should only be 1 NA in the result and it should be the first element because you cannot do a two period average with 1 element but the results above show the NA as the last element

My results should be:

```
NA
1
1.5
2.5
3.5
4.5
5.5
6.5
7.5
8.5
9.5
10
```

Comment: Divide `sum` by 2, since you want an average

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `roll_mean` from `library(RcppRoll)`

```
library(RcppRoll)
roll_mean(z,2, na.rm=TRUE)
#[1]  1.0  1.5  2.5  3.5  4.5  5.5  6.5  7.5  8.5  9.5 10.0
```

Or if we are using `rollapply` from `library(zoo)`, use `mean`

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(z, 2, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
#[1]  1.0  1.5  2.5  3.5  4.5  5.5  6.5  7.5  8.5  9.5 10.0
```

#### Update

If we wanted to have `NA` as the first element, we can use the `fill` argument along with `align`.

```
roll_mean(z,2, na.rm=TRUE, fill=NA, align='right')
#[1]   NA  1.0  1.5  2.5  3.5  4.5  5.5  6.5  7.5  8.5  9.5 10.0
```

Or using `rollapply`

```
rollapply(z, 2, mean, na.rm=TRUE, fill=NA, align='right')
#[1]   NA  1.0  1.5  2.5  3.5  4.5  5.5  6.5  7.5  8.5  9.5 10.0
```

Comment: Please see edit there should be an NA as the first element. Any thoughts.

Comment: @user3022875  Updated the post.  Hopefully, there won't be more edits.

Comment: Is there a way to make the rolling average include the NAs. Do you see how the the second element is 1 but it really should be .5 because the 2 period average of NA and 1  = 2. Is that possible?

Comment: @user3022875  I am not sure about the expected output for the last NA.  Perhaps `rollapply(replace(z, is.na(z), 0), 2, mean, na.rm=TRUE, fill=NA, align='right')`